# Skip checkout process if special field has value

Tags: 7, commerce

I want to skip the checkout process and node has bin publish for free product, but my module is not working!

Any pointers greatly appreciated

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
    if ($node['field_noeagahi']['und']['0']['value'] = 1) {
      $form_state['values']['commerce_node_checkout_skip'] = True;
      $node->status = 1;
    }
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [hook_commerce_checkout_router](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_router/7) and there check if order has product that has special field value

```
function hook_commerce_checkout_router($order, $checkout_page) {
  /*
if $order has product with special field    
drupal_goto('');
  */
}
```